# Issue in rendering marker of Mapbox-gl

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl, mapbox-marker

I am developing a Truck rental system in which I want to render markers on the source location and destination location and also display distance between these two points on top right corner of the map.
I am able to correctly get the coordinates of these two location and calculate distance correctly too, but the markers of mapboxgl : mapboxgl.Marker() on the two locations is not visible. How do I resolve the issue ?
[Attached image for example : Here I have entered two locations : Borivalli in Mumbai,India and Gachibowli in Hyderabad,India. The distance is calculated correctly on the top right corner of the image but marker is not seen on the map as expected on these two locations.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4iHf.jpg)

I wrote the following code for reference :

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./renderMap.css";
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";
import "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/dist/mapbox-gl-draw.css";

mapboxgl.accessToken =
  "{my-access-token}";

export default function RenderMap(props) {
  const [to, setTo] = React.useState(null);
  const [from, setFrom] = React.useState(null);
  const [distance, setDistance] = React.useState(null);
  async function get_val() {
    const res = await fetch(
      `http://api.positionstack.com/v1/forward?access_key={myaccesskey}&query=1600 ${area1} ${city1} ${state1} ${country1}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
      }
    )
    const resp = await res.json();
    const toPoint = [resp.data[0].longitude, resp.data[0].latitude];
    setTo(toPoint);
    const res2 = await fetch(
      `http://api.positionstack.com/v1/forward?access_key={myaccesskey}&query=1600 ${area2} ${city2} ${state2} ${country2}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
      }
    )
    const resp2 = await res2.json();
    const fromPoint = [resp2.data[0].longitude, resp2.data[0].latitude];
    setFrom(fromPoint);
    const options = { units: "miles" };
    const res3 = await fetch(
     `https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/DistanceMatrix?origins=${resp.data[0].latitude},${resp.data[0].longitude}&destinations=${resp2.data[0].latitude},${resp2.data[0].longitude}&travelMode=driving&key={mykey}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
      }
    )
    const resp3 = await res3.json();
setDistance(resp3.resourceSets[0].resources[0].results[0].travelDistance);
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: "map", // container id
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
      center: [79.384, 21.101],
      zoom: 5,
    });
    map.on("load", () => {
      if(to && from)
      {
      var greenMarker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
        color: "green",
      })
        .setLngLat(to)
        .addTo(map);

      var purpleMarker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
        color: "purple",
      })
        .setLngLat(from) // marker position using variable 'from'
        .addTo(map); //add marker to map
    }
    });
    if(distance !== null)
    {
      var value = document.getElementById("map-overlay");
      value.innerHTML = "Distance: " + distance.toFixed([2]) + " miles";
    }
    
    get_val();
  }, [distance]);

  return (
    <div id="map-container">
      <div id="map"></div>
      <div id="map-overlay">Distance: </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Following is the renderMap.css

```
#map-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#map-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Any help resolving the bug will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).